# Pentagram and Golden Ratio

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, math-history, golden-ratio

Pythagoreans used the pentagram as their mystical symbol. They believed that every number-shape had a hidden meaning and the pentagram is related with the golden ratio. My questions are:

1. The only reason why the golden ration is so famous is because of this relationships:

$\frac{\text{red}}{\text{green}}=\frac{\text{green}}{\text{blue}}=\frac{\text{blue}}{\text{purple}}=\varphi ??$

2. How can it be proved without using angles?

[image]

Comment: How can it be proven without using angles? If angles are arbitrary, you may have $6$-ends star instead as well.

Comment: Statement 1 seems unlikely unless you regard this as equivalent to $x^2=x+1$

Comment: https://www.fastcompany.com/3044877/the-golden-ratio-designs-biggest-myth

Comment: https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_05_07.html   and a very nice book by Mario Livio in his 2002 book https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0767908163/qid=1086746414/sr=2-3/ref=sr_2_3/102-0952611-6862525   The important part is that there is no credible evidence that any architects or artists used $\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$ in buildings, sculpture, paintings. Oh, the name comes from some German guy after 1800.

Comment: @Gio The (arbitrary) way that I was taught, imagine that you have a picture that has width L and height H, where L/H is the (positive) golden ratio.  Then, if the width of the picture is truncated by H, so that the new width is L-H, the resulting dimensions of H vs (L-H) will have the same ratio as the original ratio of L vs H.  This was my **informal** introduction to the golden ratio.

Comment: @WillJagy: Years ago (2005-ish), I wrote a silly computer doodad that would locate the digits of the current time (eg, "12:34") within the digits of $\pi$ or, optionally, the golden ratio. The doodad earned me a "fan email" from an architect who said his industry peers *loved* $\phi$ and typically had numerous books about it on their shelves. I personally had never much believed the hype about the golden ratio as a design darling, and I said as much to my "fan". He insisted the hype was justified. Go figure. (I'm not saying he's right. I just don't get many opportunities to tell this story. :)

Comment: @Blue Well, go figure. I had an analogous reason for finding the Livio book. I noticed that the free-standing wood altar in my church included a version of Euclid's original construction of $\phi,$ including a circular arc (Euclid just specified lengths). It turns out that the son of the minister (of some decades  ago) built this altar to honor his father; he is a fine woodworker, the altar is beautiful (top is a big rectangle of thick glass). The diagram was intended to illustrate a sort of gateway to perfection. I gave the church two copies of Livio.

Comment: @Blue   I should correct one thing. Livio was writing about da Vinci, Michaelangelo, old and established names. There is at least one modern artist  who deliberately set the golden ratio in one of his artworks, and  publicized that fact.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It can be proved using similar triangles. The purple triangle and green triangle are similar because all sides are either on the same line or parallel. The purple triangle and triangle $ABC$ are similar for obvious reason, giving ${red\over green}={green\over blue}={blue \over purple}$.

For the ratio, notice that $green+blue=red$ and ${red\over green}={green\over blue}$ so $${green+blue\over green} = {green\over blue}$$ $$({green\over blue})^2-{green\over blue}-1=0$$.